# On startup my wifi does not work 50% of the time

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, asus-laptop

So i have windows 10 home edition on a ASUS ZenBook Pro Duo. When i start the system up there is a 50/50 chance that my wifi does not work correctly. It will say connected, no internet. then i need to turn my wifi off in the system tray and restart pc. then turn it back on after a restart.

All my drivers are up to date and i got all the needed windows updates. it does seem to be a software issue since it does connect but no internet comes through. and if i try to reconnect w/o restarting it crashes the whole wifi software instead.

the laptop usualy connects to my 5Ghz wifi. i got other devices connecting to this also, but they got no issues.

EDIT:
i have looked at the logs and don't see anything weird.
[image: internet fails]

the translation for this is : No internet, secured
I still don't know why this happens.

Comment: I understand your technical frustration.  However, as it stands, your post is not a question, but a story.  More information is also necessary.  Where did you get your updated drivers?  Asus?  Windows Update?  Do you get any error messages?  What about any logs?

Comment: Is the Network Connection Icon in the system try a World-looking Icon or the "Connected" Icon. Look in your hidden icons if you do not see it displayed. Click on it and connect.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your WiFi Device disappeared or not working, then Check WiFi Driver Status. Using the Following Method

Right Click on This PC (Desktop Icon)

> Manage
> Device Manager
> Expand or Double Click > Network Adapter
> Check WiFi Driver.

If there is no WiFi Driver Present at a time. then it might be WiFi Card Issue. You have to Send your laptop to Repair Center.

Comment: added some more details to the problem